# django - aggregate data according to field in model

Tags: python, django, orm, aggregate

I have a model with a `CharField` with choices. I want to aggregate the model and get a list of all of the choices and the number of models in each choice. So if i have:

```
model1: a
model2: b
model3: c
model4: a
model5: c
model6: c
```

I want to build a django query set to get the following result (in json if i can)

```
{a: 2, b: 1, c: 3}
```

Is this even possible with the django orm or do i need to run a pure sql query?
Thanks.

Comment: It is possible and it is called [aggregating annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregating-annotations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you the `dict` you are looking for. Be careful, however, with the [order of `annotate` and `values`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-values-clauses):

```
from django.db.models import Count

d = {
    x['field_name']: x['count'] 
        for x in model.objects
            .annotate(count=Count('field_name'))  
            .values('field_name', 'count')
            .distinct()
}
```

If you want to convert this to json use the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module:

```
import json

json_string = json.dumps(d)
```